# Figure of speech for repetition of words in the middle of successive phrases, sentences or verses

Tags: figures-of-speech, repetition, poetic-devices

I know *Anaphora* is repetition of a word or expression at the beginning of successive phrases, clauses, sentences, or verses and *Epistrophe* is repetition of a word or expression at the end of successive phrases, clauses, sentences, or verses.

But what would the figure of speech or poetic device be for repetition of a word or expression in the ***middle*** of successive phrases, clauses, sentences, or verses?

For example:

> Now we will count to twelve, 
>  and we will all keep still.

This is from Pablo Neruda's *[Keeping Quiet](http://www.mindfulnesstherapy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/keeping-quiet-pablo-neruda.pdf)*.

Comment: _Anaphora_ has a different meaning in linguistics than it does in Greek litererary analysis. It refers to usage of pronouns, not noun repetition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called ***mesodiplosis***:

> ***Mesodiplosis*** is *the repetition of a word in the middle of each phrase or clause*. For example,
>
> > One, ***but not*** two; three, ***but not*** four; five, ***but not*** six.” ([LiteraryTerms](https://literaryterms.net/repetition/))

Here is an example from the KJV:

> We are afflicted in every way, but not crushed; perplexed, but not driven to despair; persecuted, but not forsaken; struck down, but not destroyed. ([2 Cor. 4:8](https://biblehub.com/2_corinthians/4-8.htm))

Here is one from Shakespeare:

> But ***till that time*** 
>  Come not thou near me. 
>  And when ***that time*** comes, 
>  Afflict me with thy mocks, pity me not, 
>  As ***till that time*** I shall not pity thee. *[As You Like It](https://myshakespeare.me/shakespeares-works/elements/figures-of-speech/by-name/mesodiplosis/)*, 3.5.39.